# Как добавить элемент в нужном порядке в массив(Python)

Tags: python

Не могу понять как можно в питоне добавить данные в словарик(массив) на определенный индекс, не используя цилк `for` и `append`.

Данные возвращает фильтр Solr, но присваиваются они не верным образом (`append`).

А мне нужно чтобы данные содержались следующим образом, я пока что для примера добавил их в ручную :

```
clean_data = {
    'results': [ 
        {
            'name': u'Classic',
            'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Classic'
        },
        {
            'name': u'Common',
            'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Common'
        }
    ]
}
```

К примеру, объект `Classic` находиться под индексом `[0]`, за ним сразу под индексом `[1]` добавился объект `common`.

Конечно же я мог бы применить `for-loop`, и append, но это создает проблему, при повторном обращении объект common записывается под индексом [0], а classic под[1],а нужно чтобы коллекция была неизменной т.е `dict[common[0],classic[1]]`, а не `dict[common[0]], dict[common[1]]`, ввиду логики Solr.

И по этому хотелось бы изначально - назначать индекс[] входящего объекта, и менять размер коллекции в зависимости от - количества входящих данных.
в C коде это делалось следующим образом : `dict.length = 1` ; `dict[0] = 'common'`, либо `dict.set(0) = 'common'` , а вот как это же сделать в питон. Суть в том чтобы не добавлять данные через `for` И `append`, т.к. в этом по-моему и проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу такие варианты: заранее заполнить список пустыми значениями, например, None и впоследствии их заменять по их индексам:

```
clean_data = {
    'results': None
}

# Добавление 10 пустых записей
clean_data['results'] = [None for _ in range(10)]

clean_data['results'][0] = {
    'name': u'Classic',
    'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Classic'
}

clean_data['results'][3] = {
    'name': u'Common',
    'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Common'
}
```

Или вместо списка использовать ассоциативный массив (словарь), в котором ключом будет индекс, тогда не нужно будет заморачиваться с заполнением списка:

```
clean_data = {
    'results': dict()
}

clean_data['results'][0] = {
    'name': u'Classic',
    'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Classic'
}

clean_data['results'][3] = {
    'name': u'Common',
    'select_url': '/ru/catalogue/category/Common'
}
```

Comment: а как выглядит такой словарик в питоне ?

Comment: Фигурные скобки с ключами и значениями -- словарь. Квадратные скобки -- список. Просто фигурные скобки со значениями -- множество. Круглые скобки -- кортеж. Для создания этих коллекций есть встроенные функции, соответственно: dict, list, set и tuple

Comment: А ясно не заметил изменений, я просто не совсем понимаю проблему, толи solr переформировывает данные и они присваиваются в словарь, либо что-то другое. И может ее следует решить по другому, проверять входящие данные, на наличие изменений(добавление индексов соларом), и только если эти данные не находятся в словарике записывать уже, а то по-моему получается так что при запросе, записанные данные опять обрабатываются(причем не правильно), как бы их статичными сделать ?На выходе у меня вот такая гадость - http://i.imgur.com/EaDcc9V.png?2 http://i.imgur.com/ObfzssL.png?1 - common поменял индекс

Comment: Лучше, проверяйте на наличие изменений. Вопрос по solr уже не относится к этому вопросу, лучше создайте отдельный с соответствующей меткой, кодом и примерами данных. И если мой ответ вас устраивает, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: @gli9red окей, просто стараюсь решить проблему по проще, если такое вообще возможно, а со славариками питона не было особого опыта - так что спасибо

Comment: @gli9red Только 1 момент, есть - как будет выглядеть словарь - если данные которые записываются динамичны, т.е берутся из источника x,

Comment: Словари питона не отличаются от словарей в других языках. Посмотрите литературу по ассоциативным массивами, т.е. словарям. Их еще называют map/dict. В комментарии эту тему не поднять -- ограничения на оформление и размер комментария :)

Comment: а как можно - не используя цикл for, привести вид словаря -`{0: set([('/ru/catalogue/category/Classic', 'Classic')]), 1: set([('/ru/catalogue/category/Common', 'Common')])}` в обычный тип, т.е без ключа 0 и 1 в `[ {[('/ru/catalogue/category/Classic', 'Classic')]},{[('/ru/catalogue/category/Classic', 'Classic')]} ]`

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно такой результат? У вас в списке находится множество, внутри которого список, внутри которого кортеж, зачем? Без цикла можно создать, используя генератор: `d = {0: set([('/ru/catalogue/category/Classic', 'Classic')]), 1: set([('/ru/catalogue/category/Common', 'Common')])}
print([v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])])`